# mt-5 h not working for textarea in tailwind css in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

hello i am facing a issue with react tailwind text area , i am tring to apply `mt-5` but it is not working. When i added using `style={{marginTop:"1.25rem"}}` it is working , similarly properties like height margin ... are not applying to text area in react

```js
function (){
  return (
    <div className=" w-24 m-5">
      <input placeholder="name" className="pl-2 rounded-sm" />
      <textarea className=" mt-5"></textarea>
      <button className="mt-5 bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 px-2 py-1 hover:bg-black hover:text- white rounded-sm hover:underline">
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i actually find a problem that the react is adding a additional style to the textarea and that is overwriting the textarea, i find this is inspector, in textarea there is a additional style 
[image]

how can i avoid this aditional style and who is adding it, is it tailwind or react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was not problem with tailwind nor react , it was my browser and extensions, i removed those extensions and it is working